# How do I use JSON data stored in FutureBuilder's snapshot.data (without class)?

Tags: json, flutter

```
 return loading ? Loading() : FutureBuilder(
      future: SaadConstants.getJsonLanguagePack(),// edit pls
      builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot)
      {
        if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
          return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
        }

     // rest of code
```

**My getJsonLanguagePack():**

```
  static Future<String > getJsonLanguagePack() async {
      SharedPreferences pref = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
      return json.decode(pref.getString('languagePack')); // languagePack Exists as String already locally containing all the json file content (local json file)
  }
```

**My JSON file :**

```
[
    {"key":"registerNew", "value":"Nouveau ?" },
    {"key":"emailPlaceHolder", "value":"Entrez votre email." },
    {"key":"passwordPlaceHolder", "value":"Entrez votre mot de pass." },
    {"key":"rememberMe", "value":"rester connecté." },
    {"key":"forgotPass", "value":"Pass oublié ?" },
    {"key":"loginBtn", "value":"Connexion" },
    {"key":"_or_", "value":"_OU_" }]
```

I tried to return Future> on my  getJsonLanguagePack
but it raises an error inside FutureBuilder saying that String is not subtype of Map

The problem is when I try to access snapshot.data. I cant use keys that I defined in my JSON file to get the value I want.

As it is conciliated as Array of chars.

Thanks a lot .

Comment: If u are trying to use keys you would probably want to return `Map<String, dynamic>` instead of `String` in your `getJsonLanguagePack()` future callback.

Comment: @SlahLayouni Yea that is what i first did , but then i get Error  saying type String is not subtype of type FutureOr<Map<String,dynamic>>

Comment: Can you edit your question and add an example of your json file ? and how you are saving it in pref ?

Comment: Your json is an array, so you should be returning `List<dynamic>` instead of string

Comment: @SlahLayouni no matter what i return i get the error above .


  static Future<List<dynamic>> getJsonLanguagePack() async {
      SharedPreferences pref = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
      return (json.decode(pref.getString('languagePack')) as List<dynamic>);
  }

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/206001/discussion-between-med-nour-and-slah-layouni).

Comment: Can you show how do you use `snapshot.data`?

Comment: @AugustinR i just checked if  snapshot.hasError and  yes it has ... still no use of data yet .

Comment: Are you sure that you did not write `FutureBuilder<String>` ?

Comment: @AugustinR no .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to duplicate json file data into `SharePreference`. You can directly use them

```
import 'dart:convert';

import "package:flutter/material.dart";
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: HomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class HomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  static Future<Map<String, String>> loadJsonLanguage(String langName) async {
    final jsonString = await rootBundle
        .loadString('assets/app_languages/' + langName + '.json');
    List translationList = jsonDecode(jsonString);
    final mappedTranslation = <String, String>{};
    translationList.forEach((dynamic item) {
      mappedTranslation[item["key"]] = item["value"];
    });
    return mappedTranslation;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: FutureBuilder(
        future: loadJsonLanguage("ar"),
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting)
            return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
          else if (snapshot.hasError)
            return Center(child: Text("${snapshot.error}"));
          return Center(child: Text(snapshot.data["registerNew"]));
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: holy !
lol you a life saver :D 
Realy best of the best Flutter's related Question helpers .
thanks lots .

Comment: Thank you. I am just improving myself by solving problems here :)